# Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Gmail Scheduler

Tags: gmail, scheduler

How can I deactivate the

```
"Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Gmail Scheduler"
```

message I keep getting everyday?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To revoke a script's access to your data, visit the [permissions page](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions) for your Google account. Click the name of the script whose authorization you want to revoke, then click Revoke access on the right.